# PHP MYSQL Update values in database from a form with button

Tags: php, sql, database, psql

***Hey guys!***

I have a *assignment* at my webdevelopent class, where I have to create a restaurant website with an ***admin page where the user can update the weekly menu, that is shown on the website.***

So, a part of my ***admin.php*** looks like this:

```
print "<h1> Weekly menu </h1>";
print "<table border=1>
<tr>
<h2>Monday weekly menu.</h2>
<th>Apperitive/th>
<th>Main dish</th>
</tr>";
    print '<form action="update.php" method="post" name="update">';
    print '<td><input type="text" name="first_value"> </td>';
    print '<td><input type="text" name="second_value"> </td>';
    print '<td><input type="submit" name="Frissites" value="update"> </td>';
    print "</form>";
    print "</tr>";`
```

Sorry, you will find some hungarian words in the code, thats because I'm from Hungary....:)

And the ***update.php*** looks like this:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
require_once("functions.php");
$connect=dbconnect();
if(isset($_POST["Frissites"]))
{
    $sql="UPDATE hetimenu SET elso='".$_POST["first_value"]."', masodik='".$_POST["second_value"]."' WHERE id='1'";
    $query=pg_exec($connect,$sql);
}
?>
```

here in the table you can find elso (means first) and masodik (second). These rows has created values and thats what I would like to update, by writing in the from the foods that you want to be in the database, and shown on the site. By pressing the Update button, it should update it...but actually nothing happens. :(

I showed to my teacher, he said he cant see any problem with it and the doesnt know whats the problem with it.

Thank you for the answers! :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The title says MySQL, but then there's a <psql> tag...)

Comment: Side note: `<form>` cannot be made a child of `<table>`.

Comment: damn, yes... I wrote wrong dbm.......yes, psql.... Thanks :)!

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Add `print($sql)` and try to run it manually to see if the problem is the query itself.  Couple notes for your HTML: **1** Put the table inside the `<form>`.  **2** Inside your first line, `<h2>` is not surrounded by `<th>` or `<td>`.  **3** your last line is `</tr>` but there is no matching `<tr>` higher up.  **4** look at `<thead>` and `<tbody>` for your `<table>`. **5**  Your first table row has 2 elements, your second row (the form) has 3.  They should match.  **6**  Instead of putting the `<h2>` in the table, you can use `<legend>` on the `<form>`  **7** use CSS for the table border.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using too many prints? and just close your PHP brackets while you write HTML tags, for example

```
... your php code
?> //closes PHP code
<h1> Weekly menu </h1>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<h2>Monday weekly menu.</h2>
<th>Apperitive/th>
<th>Main dish</th>
</tr>";
<form action="update.php" method="post" name="update">
<td><input type="text" name="first_value"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="second_value"> </td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Frissites" value="update"> </td>
</form>
</tr>
<?php ...continue with your php code
```

And did you try to debug your code?

Please take your time and check a guide on how to use xdebug with your IDE.

By the way, pg_exec is deprecated, use pg_query instead. And your id should be numeric so your query should be using "WHERE id = 1"

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys thanks for everybody whos answered! Overall I put the whole 2 codes into 1 php.
It looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   $update="UPDATE hetimenu SET first='".$_POST["soup"]."', second='".$_POST["maindish"]."' WHERE id=".$_POST["days"];
   $query=pg_exec($connect,$update);
   header("Location: miksoo_admin.php");
   }
print '<hr>';
print '<form name="foodform" method="post">';
print '<select name="days">
<option value="1">Monday</option>
<option value="2">Thursday</option>
<option value="3">Wednesday</option>
</select>';
print '<input type="text" name="soup" value="">';
print '<input type="text" name="maindish" value="">';
print '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">';
print "</form>";
```